# Com4J MS Sapi Helper Functions

Tags: java, sapi, com4j

I've got problems with generating the Helper Functions of MS Sapi 5.4 with Com4j. I have to replace the combination of SAPI and Java/JNI with Com4j.
For Example, I want to use the AssignFormat Method of CSpStreamFormat.
A simple text to speech was no problem, so i can say that it works in basics.
Any one who knows how to access the full method set (especially helper functions) of sapi 5.4 via com4j?

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: I can't show you this week, but I generated the java files from sapi.dll . As I saw, they are in the example files of com4j, too. It's the speech example. Second what i realized was that the helper functions of sapi are defined in extra header files, e.g. sphelper.h
So i would need to use this h.-files with com4j. Is their a possibility to generate java code with com4j to use header files (additional to the dll)?

Answer (score 0):

`sphelper.h` is just a set of macros and static functions.  As such, a mechanical translation from C++ to Java is your best option.  Not being terribly familiar with Java, I can't recommend anything, but a quick google search provides some alternatives.

Comment: Translate the few functions, i use, from c++ to java was my first idea too. But problem is that com4j did not 100% generated sapi to use with java. There are some methods missing, not only in my generated code, also in the example -com4jdir-/samples/speech/. Which is the generated Java code of Sapi created by the com4j developer, i found out.